# Rhythmbox - How to get an iHeart radio station to play

Tags: 16.04, sound, rhythmbox, plugins

In attempting to play an iHeart radio station with Rhythmbox under Ubuntu 16.04 I get two error messages. Rhythmbox is working correctly with the default sample radio stations.

The first error message: "*Your Gstreamer is missing a plug-in*".

The other error message: "*Rhythmbox requires to install plugins to play media files of the following type: application/x-gzip decoder.*"

How can the missing requirements be installed to enable Rhythmbox to play an iHeart radio station?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved. Found this post: [How to get streaming url from online streaming radio station](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21158164/how-to-get-streaming-url-from-online-streaming-radio-station). The error messages were spurious.

Essentially, you look at the page source and search on the word "`stream`". Then copy the link into the Rhythmbox URL field. In the case of the iHeart radio station, there were several "`stream`" links. Copied them one by one until I got the right one.